# how to use a variable as spark selected fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm fresh with scala, there's a dataframe with lots of columns, I would like to select some fields but have to list them all every time as below, how can I define a variable stands for them and pass in scala?

```
df.select("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
```

expected:

```
df.select(variable val)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a list of columns, something like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val fields = List("a", "b", "c", "d").map(col)
df.select(fields: _*)
```

`map(col)` transforms your list of strings into columns.
`fields: _*` transforms your `List` into multiple arguments